# BadImageFormatException but all assemblies are AnyCPU (PE32) or 64-bit (PE32+)

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I get `BadImageFormatException` when running a unit test in VS2013. The error occurs in a call to `Assembly.LoadFrom`.

Configuration is Debug x64.  In this configuration all assemblies are set to build AnyCPU or x64.

TEST | Test Settings | Default Processor Architecture is set to X64.

Wrote a little utility to run CorFlags on each assembly in the test directory.  Every assembly is either PE32 (AnyCPU) or PE32+ (x64 only) and no assembly has 32BITREQ or 32BITPREF.

Any idea where this error is coming from?

Comment: It looks like you are loading an assembly which has dependencies on a 32-bit (a-ka x86) mode DLL (outside of your test directory), perhaps. Which assembly fails to load?

Comment: Please copy the full exception message as well as `corflags assembly_name` output and paste them above. Your description of "PE32 (AnyCPU) or PE32+ (x64 only)" is inaccurate. You should not suppose that we have the super power to watch your screen remotely.

Comment: Is your test runner set for 32bit or 64bit?